# How do you invoke a function on a bunch of lines selected via Ctrl-v?

Tags: python, vim

I am selecting some text via Ctrl-v (visual mode). Then I type
\s to align those lines and sort them like so:

```
"Strip trailing space
 :map <Leader>S :1,$ s/\s\+$//g<CR>
:imap <Leader>S :1,$ s/\s\+$//g<CR>
```

How do I pass all the selected lines to Sort(). I thought the
**vim.current.range** object might do it but that didn't work out.
Currently the Sort() function reads text 1 line at a time via
cr[0]. What I need to do is store the split lines in a matrix,
compute the required length/column and print them out into the
buffer.

```
function! Sort()
python << EOF
import vim
cr = vim.current.range
line = cr[0]
line = line.split()
fmt_str = ['%8s' for word in line]
fmt_str = ' '.join(fmt_str)

line = tuple([word for word in line])
print(fmt_str)
cr[0]= fmt_str % line
EOF
endfunction

"Sort and align
:map <Leader>s :call Sort()<CR>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want a mapping to work on the visual selection, you need to use `:vnoremap`. An Ex command (like `:call`) will then automatically have the visual range `'<,'>` prepended. An ordinary function would then be invoked once per line, but you can define a special kind of function (cp. `:help function-range-example`) that handles the range itself.

Since you seem to want to use Python, I'd just drop the prepended range via `<C-u>` and access the selection's bounds via the `<` and `>` marks, then access and modify the lines via `vim.current.buffer[lnum]`:

```
:vnoremap <Leader>s :<C-u>call Sort()<CR>
function! Sort()
    ...
    start = vim.current.buffer.mark('<')[0]
    end = vim.current.buffer.mark('>')[0]
```